# ScatterView from Surface 2.0 SDK in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, multi-touch

I am looking to implement something like the ScatterView control from the Surface 2.0 SDK in my WPF application. I want to have a canvas for freely manipulating items with multi-touch support.

See here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.scatterview.aspx

As I understand, the Surface 2.0 SDK is no longer used. Is there a similar ScatterView functionality or library I can use in my WPF application without having to reinvent the wheel myself?

Thanks